# JBoss EAP 6.1 Console spinning

Tags: javascript, jboss

I downloaded JBoss EAP 6.1 on my Windows 7 box and I'm experiencing an error when I try to access the management console.  I already added a user via the add-user.bat but when I try to access the console I am getting an endless spinning loading gif with this error in the console:

> Uncaught JavaScript exception [Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier] in , line 22

I've tried in all major browsers on their latest editions (Chrome, Opera, Firefox, and IE).

Has anyone else experienced this? Any pointers on how to fix it?

Comment: I can't duplicate this, Dan. IE 10.0.9200.16736, Firefox 25.0.1, Chrome 31.0.1650.57 m, Safari 5.1.7; all on Windows 7. Perhaps some sort of plug-in or cache issue? Seems unlikely across all those browsers, but you couldn't hurt to try clearing cache and disabling plug-ins.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. It was the GWT Development Plugin/add-on. I uninstalled it and it worked fine from that point on.  It was the same for IE 10, Firefox 25, and Chrome 32.